# how to import class object in python from another file

Tags: python-3.x

Suppose I have a directory with files `classfile.py` and a `test_classfile.py`

here's `classfile.py`

```py
class Student:

     def __init__(self, fname, lname):
          self.firstname = fname
          self.lastname = lname

     def printname(self):
          return (self.firstname + self.lastname)


if __name__ == '__main__':
     s = Student('John', 'Doe')
```

What I'd like to do is import just the object `s`
into the `test_file.py`

something like this,

```py
from dir.classfile.Student import s


def test_classfile():
    assert str(s.printname()).isalpha()
```

I get the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dir.classfile.Student'; 'dir.classfile' is not a package
```

Comment: What do you think this line does? `if __name__ == '__main__':` There are other things wrong here but to me this is the most blatant one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is said 'dir.classfile' is not a package. If your .py files are both in the same directory, you just do 'import classfile'. Suppose the classfile.py was in the different directory, you would have to do the following:

```
import os.path
path_to_mods = os.path.abspath('path/to/classfile')
sys.path.insert(0, path_to_mods)
import classfile
```

You cannot import from 'Student' - this is an object. But you can import Student like this:

```
from classfile import Student
```

Also you cannot import instance of the class which is s. You should import the object like it it said above and then create an instance of it.